# Удаление дерева нерекурсивным методом

Tags: c++, дерево

Правильно ли я понимаю, что для удаления всего дерева нерекурсивным методом (допускается использование стека/очереди) надо сначала пройтись по всем ее узлам горизонтальным методом и запихнуть их все в очередь, а потом уже пройтись по содержимому очереди, удаляя все узлы? То есть удаление будет как бы происходить снизу-вверх.

Заранее спасибо за ответы, за примеры скажу отдельное спасибо, т.к. только учусь

Comment: Я бы посоветовал удалять так же как и простой 2 направленный список

Comment: Это как? Добавить указатель на родителя к каждому узлу?

Comment: Я бы в этом случае моделировал рекурсию, записывая в программный стек адреса узлов, от которых идем влево